# How to create enabling Wifi for better accuracy popup?

Tags: ios, popup, location, wifi, settings

Some location based app alerts the users with a popup

- Title: "Location"
- Message: "Enabling Wi-Fi in Settings will improve your location accuracy."
- Options: "OK" and "Settings."

I know that this is not a custom alert view because I see the same alert from many applications. Anyone have a clue how to programmatically show this popup?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there is not way to manually show that popup.

It pops up only when you have not been using gps for a while.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45515/53902